# using textInput in Shiny flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Happy New Year.
I am trying to make multiple linear regression app using shiny.
I use a textInput for the independent variables part to use in the lm() formula as below:

```
textInput("multiLinearReg","R Formula for features for multiple linear regression:")

mlg = eventReactive(input$goP4,{
  data = Train_Test()
  dataM = data['Train']$Train
  dataM = as.data.frame(dataM)
  target = dataM$Sale_Price
  
  model1 = lm(target ~ input$multiLinearReg,data=dataM)
  result = list("Summary"=summary(model1),"Confidence Interval"=confint(model1,level=input$confInt))
  result
})

renderPrint({
 mlg()
})
```

but I keep getting this `error variable lengths differ (found for 'input$multiLinearReg')`

I don't know how to resolve it.
Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: as the error says the problem is with `lm(target ~ input$multiLinearReg,data=dataM)`, print what `input$multiLinearReg` is

Comment: so when I right MS_SubClass in the text field I get 
[1] "MS_SubClass" when I use renderPrint({input$multiLinearReg})

Answer (score 0):

I actually find a solution that works for me as follows:

```
mlg = eventReactive(input$goP4,{
  data = Train_Test()
  dataM = data['Train']$Train
  dataM = as.data.frame(dataM)
  target = 'Sale_Price'
  feature = eval(expression(input$multiLinearReg))[[1]]
  formula = as.formula(paste(target,'~',feature))
  model1 = lm(formula,data=dataM)
  result = list("Summary"=summary(model1),"Confidence Interval"=confint(model1,level=input$confInt))
  result
})

renderPrint({
 mlg()
})
```